# How to start an activity by tapping notification of phonegap android status bar LocalNotification plugin?

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, localnotification

I'm developing an android application with phoneGap and LocalNotification plugin.

As for the notifications part, it's already working no problem there.

I just want the app to open when I tap the notification.

As Gmail app, when an email arrives to the status bar we can tap it and open the app/activity.

The local Notification plugin URL : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification

Let me know , if you don't understand what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I guess you need to write your question in a clearer way so that you get some useful answers :)

Comment: Check out the answer to this question over here:
[Clear Android's Local Notifications cordova plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798021/clear-androids-local-notifications-cordova-plugin)